# sum of column data in jqgrid mvc4

Tags: jqgrid, column-sum

I'm fetching data to jqgrid from database and displaying. here the question is , I've to display the sum of numeric column data in footer . Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in your grid definition,

```
footerrow : true,
userDataOnFooter : true,
gridComplete : function() {
    var totalcount = $("#grid").jqGrid('getCol', 'column_name',
        false, 'sum');
    $("#grid").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', {
        display_column_name : 'Total Records',
        column_name : totalcount
     });
 }
```

You need to use your column name at `(column_name)` and to display text nearest left column name `(display_column_name)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: This works great for all the displayed records (the records returned for a given page), but do you know of a way to display the total for all pages and not just the page the user is on?